# PHP get checkbox value's separated by comma's

Tags: php, forms

I have a contact form with a couple of checkboxes. 
Whenever i submit the form I would like the selected value's to be printed separated by comma's.

```
<form  method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product1" value="12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product1" value="13">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product3" name="product1" value="14">
  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I'm using this form. Lets say product 1 and 2 are selected. Then it should print 12,13 < 
What is the best way to do this? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

USE CASE:

So I thought it was useful to post why I need this.

Later when I'm able to get the values I will do something like this:

`header("Location: http://test.com/$myvalues");`

So this link can be `test.com/12,13` after the user submits the form.

Not working:

So im using this code

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['product'])){
    $values =  implode(',',$_POST['product']);
    // header("Location: https://test.com/?add-to-cart=$values");
  }
  ?>
```

Whenever i click on the submit button, it takes me to a page that doesnt exist. So i get a 404 page. Even with the header location commented off. 
The header location doesnt seem to work at all.

Comment: You want to show the selected values on the webpage before user submits it?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i added an use case to it. So after basically

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  method="POST" action="upload.php" >
  <input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product[]" value="12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product[]" value="13">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product3" name="product[]" value="14">
  <button type="submit" name="products" >Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

in upload.php

```
$a=$_POST['product'];
$prodt=implode(',',$a);
```

$prodt has the value

Comment: why you gave a duplicate answer? I have given the same solution 13 min back.

Answer (score 0):

To consolidate Alive to Die's answer and the comments about XSS by hanshenrik;

Use the array-like syntax in the input name attribute:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product[]" value="12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product[]" value="13">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product3" name="product[]" value="14">
  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

If you check the first two checkboxes and submit, you should receive:
`$POST['product'] == ["12", "13"];`

Of course any input needs to be validated and escaped before outputting in the response. For the specific use-case you mention, you would end up with something like this:

```
$products = [];
if (isset($POST['product'])) {
    foreach ($POST['product'] as $product) {
        if (!is_numeric($product)) {
            die("invalid product value.");
        }
        $products[] = intval($product);
    }
}

if (empty($products)) {
    die("no products selected.");
}

header("Location: https://test.com/" . implode(",", $products);
```

**Clarification on input validation:**

If you skip the input validation, one could submit the following data:
`product[]="admin.php"` and get redirected to `https://test.com/admin.php`. Of course that wasn't what you wanted this script to do, so by that principle alone you should consider restricting the possible behavior of your code. But it could get worse:

If you choose to `echo implode(",", $POST['product'])` somewhere in your website, someone might submit:
`product[]="<script>alert(\"vuln\");</script>"` which will add JavaScript to your website. An alert isn't dangerous, but this script could be anything. From submitting your session cookies to running a cryptominer in your browser. In principle, if you can `alert()`, you can do anything.

If you construct your original form from a database, someone might insert malicious inputs as values into the database. So these attacks are not necessarily limited to a single user playing around with their element inspector.

These are a lot of 'ifs' and for a simple local website or PHP script, you don't need to concern yourself with most of these issues. However, if you choose to make any of your code available to the internet, you should never trust user input.

Comment: the lengthy process to check values as well as unnecessary. PHP smart enough to handle that itself.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've added some clarification on why input validation is necessary. A simple `implode()` call like in your answer is definitely not sufficient to prevent attacks.

Comment: I don't get all that stuff: adding `admin.php` as an option sounds like an attack, but why should I go this complicated way and not call that page directly? And no, script tags are not written to that page if `header()` is used. There is no `echo` for the product IDs given

Comment: @NicoHaase You misunderstood. using `value="admin.php"` is not a use-case, that's an attack to make the script misbehave. Indeed if you wanted to redirect to `admin.php`, you wouldn't use this method. `header()` also writes to the response payload, just not to the body. If you can manipulate the header, you can also change the behavior of the script.

Comment: @Kevin.a sorry, typo in my code. I recommend using a code editor that can spot these issues for you instead of a simple text editor.

Comment: Writing a header does not influence the body. Adding some script tags to `Location: myVulnerableURL` does not cause harm unless the script triggered is itself vulnerable - but then you should not fix it through sanitizing header parameters

Comment: @NicoHaase Besides scripts with side-effects (deleting accounts, etc.), the URL could literally point anywhere. From local file systems to application specific protocols. Just a few months ago, Electrum was found to have a critical vulnerability that could cause code execution by targeting the specific URL of an application. This has nothing to do with PHP vulnerabilities, but it *could be triggered* by PHP code that doesn't sanitize user input or blindly trusts database strings, etc. I've never seen anyone advocate **not** sanitizing input.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've given every checkbox the same `name` attribute, you can't. Give them separate names and you can easily handle this client and/or server side.